# How to implement AVPlayer in SwiftUI in a correct way?

Tags: ios, swiftui, avplayer

I am having a couple of problems with player. I know there are many player examples but almost all of them are designed to play just one url and does not have the functionalities that I want.

First of all this is my existing code for the player:

```
struct PlayerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var video: Video

    private let player = AVPlayer()

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerVC.player = self.player
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        } catch(let error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        playerVC.player?.play()

        return playerVC
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        guard let url = URL(string: video.url) else { return }

        resetPlayer(uiViewController)

        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)           
        uiViewController.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        uiViewController.player?.play()
        if((uiViewController.view.window) == nil)
        {
            uiViewController.player?.pause()
        }
        print("Player::UpdatePlayer: Player updated")
    }

    func resetPlayer(_ vc: AVPlayerViewController) {
        vc.player?.pause()
        vc.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        print("Player::ResetPlayer: Player reseted.!")
    }


}

struct Video: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var url: String


}
```

And I use it as follows. This is just example I replace the str with button action in the actual project.

```
struct TestTestView: View {
    @State var str: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        PlayerViewController(video: Video(id: 2, url: (str == "") ? chan.getDVR()[0].getHlsStreamURL() : self.str ))
    }
}
```

Now the code above works up to a point. It plays, you can update the url with button click and it plays the new url. But when it enters the fullscreen the video stops, because it updates the whole player although nothing changed. The following lines makes it pause when entering the fullscreen mode:

```
        if((uiViewController.view.window) == nil)
        {
            uiViewController.player?.pause()
        }
```

However, If I remove those lines when I navigate to another screen it continues to play you keep hearing the sound. I tried to detect the fullscreen to update my code but I was not able to do it. I tried to detect I the player is actually in the screen but it did not work as well. So what is the correct  way to implement it. Basically I want to do:

1 - Be able to update the player and play different streams
2 - Starts auto play 
3 - Smoothly continue to play when switching in and out of full screen mode
4 - Stop when navigated to another screen.

By the way if it is not in full screen mode I cannot click on play button or progress bar but somehow I can click on the mute or fullscreen button. I need help!!